# Reset UICollectionView on change cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am working on a quiz app based on [this tutorial](https://github.com/Akhilendra/Quiz-App-iOS). The tutorial assumes all questions contain image. However, for my case not all questions contains image. So I modified the [QuizCVCell.swift](https://github.com/Akhilendra/Quiz-App-iOS/blob/master/Quiz2/QuizCVCell.swift) as below. if `imgName` is empty, then the image won't be set. Besides, `btn1` will be placed directly under `lblQue` if there is no image. If there is image, `btn1` will be placed under image.

```
guard let unwrappedQue = question else { return }
lblQue.text = unwrappedQue.questionText
btn1.setTitle(unwrappedQue.options[0], for: .normal)
btn2.setTitle(unwrappedQue.options[1], for: .normal)
btn3.setTitle(unwrappedQue.options[2], for: .normal)
btn4.setTitle(unwrappedQue.options[3], for: .normal)

if unwrappedQue.imgName.isEmpty {
    btn1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lblQue.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive=true
} else {
    imgView.image = UIImage(named: unwrappedQue.imgName)
    btn1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive=true
}
```

This works fine, but problem occurs when I press next to move to the next question. If the current question do not contains image but the next question do has image, then the image in the next question will fail to be showed on changing cell. How to solve this? Is it I need to reset the `UICollectionView` on change cell?

Answer (score 1):

Every time you using `constraint` you add new `NSLayoutConstraint`-object. After cell reusing they start conflicting each other.

You should construct all the constraints once in `awakeFromNib`-method and store its references. Then just change `isActive` properties according to image precedence.